# Swift: Firestore adding new data gives error

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

Using Firestore, I'm trying to add a new collection and document. I keep getting "Missing or insufficient permissions". What's the problem? What permission do I still need?

```
struct FirestoreReferenceManager {
  static let db = Firestore.firestore()
  static let root = db.collection("dev").document("dev")
}
```

ViewController

```
 @IBAction func handleRegistration(_ sender: Any) {
    FirestoreReferenceManager.root.collection("cities").document("LA").setData(["name": "Los Angeles", "state": "CA"]) { (err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error writing document:", err.localizedDescription)
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

go to `Database` -> Rules -> Change `allow read, write:` **if false** to **if** **request.auth != null**

or

go to `Database` -> Rules -> Change `allow read, write:` **if false** to **if true**

> **It turns off security for the database!**
>
> It is not recommended solution for production environment but you can
>   use for only testing purposes

More you can find here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Comment: thank you it works! I've work on Firestore over the summer and I didn't run into this problem. Is changing the rules something new?

Comment: It's not even recommended to turn off security for development.  It's best to implement proper rules as you develop, else anyone who knows the name of your project can make any changes they want, without even using the app.

Comment: @DougStevenson is right, it is for testing purpose only

Answer (score 0):

Please perform this step :

1) Open [console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) and open your project

2) Open database -> Cloud Firestore

3) Click on RULES

4) Make **allow read, write: if true** instead of **if false**

```
service cloud.firestore {   match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /<some_path>/ {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }   } }
```

Make **allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null** instead of **if false**

```
service cloud.firestore {   match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /<some_path>/ {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }   } }
```

This will set permission for read and write data on firestore.